# Changing varchar size for MySQL

Tags: mysql, varchar

Certainly a noobish question, but I got to ask. Once I have set VARCHAR size to 10 for my MySQL table. At, that point of time I assumed data size wouldn't be more than 10.

But, later on while updating new data, or collating new data from csv through phpmyadmin is it possible for me adjust the VARCHAR size automatically to higher size say 12. Obviously, in this case I din't know that new data is exceeding the limit.

In case, where data table is getting updated everyday, it should automatically set its VARCHAR size by itself by determining maximum incoming data size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why cant you just set the varchar size to a reasonable value depending on the data you are expecting? If your data size varies that much you make it varchar(255) or even text.
You cant make it dynamic that way at least in phpmyadmin. In theory if you have some kind of upload script in php or something you could check the max size your your input data and then run an sql query to update your database schema but IMO its not worth it the time and trouble to do this. I cant think of any reason why you want to do this.